# Max connection pool reached

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a simple SQL statement, which I would like to call quite a few times in a short time (~400 calls in < 10 seconds). After reaching about 200 calls, I get the following SQL error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.'

I have read a bunch of posts about this error. All of them recommend either wrapping your code with a `using` block or to call the `.Close()` method of the SQL connection in the end. I have implemented both, and it still does not work. Have I not implemented it correctly? (the method works fine, when not called repeatedly).

My code looks like this:

```
public static ObjectModel GetObject(int objGroupId, DateTime date)
{
    ObjectModel obj = new ObjectModel () { EffectiveFrom = date };

    // Get connection string from the App.Config file
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[GetObjectData]", connection))
        {
            // Request the data which were in force on the specified date
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = obj.EffectiveFrom;
            command.Parameters.Add("@ObjecGrouptId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = objGroupId;

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    int objId = reader.GetInt32NullIsZero("Id");
                    decimal value = reader.GetDecimalNullIsZero("value");
                    SetObjData(obj, objId, value);
                }
            }
        }

        connection.Close();
    }                

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Is this the only code that opens a connection?

Comment: Do these calls overlap? The default maximum pool size is 100. If you're trying to fire off more than 100 queries in *parallel*, you'll get this error. You can bump the `MaxPoolSize`, or else find a way to serialize calls.

Comment: I also suggest to check your store procedure, if you can optimize it's execution time.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis this is where the error is thrown, every time, without exceptions. I suspect it would throw the exception from other methods too, if it occurred there. It is called other places, but it should always be wrapped in a `using` block.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have made to attempts to make this process parallel, so if it is, it is by accident.

Comment: Im wondering if the garbage collection is lagging. as a test only, does the problem still exist if you call `GC.Collect()` and `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers` methods between each call. obviously this is not optimal, though it might point to a GC if it fixes the issue. failing that you can raise you connection limit also just pushing the problem down the road

Comment: The other thing you can do, since you a smashing this 400 times in 10 seconds. is reuse the connection sparingly, though to me smells a little as well

Comment: @TheGeneral GC isn't a factor here; the `using` releases the *underlying* connection to the pool; how long the `SqlConnection` object takes to be collected is irrelevant

Comment: Is there any chance you have `TransactionScope` or similar that might be holding on to connections (by enlisting them into a DTC scope, for example)?

Comment: @TheGeneral what I am doing is a one-time thing. Normally the method is used only a few times each minute. The `GC` methods was a good idea, but they do not seem to fix anything.

Comment: This looks like the old `THREADPOOL` issue:  https://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2011/10/25/troubleshooting-threadpool-waits/

Comment: @MJH I would expect that to throw a different exception; the "The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached" scenario is *very* specific - and is a feature of the client library, not the server; `THREADPOOL` waits are server-side.

Comment: @Marc Gravell - You are right, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

The code you show *looks* clean; all the correct `using` etc are there. This makes me suspect that something *outside* this code is holding onto the connection and tying up the pool. The **only** thing I'm aware of that functions like that is: ambient transactions, i.e. `TransactionScope`.

As a debugging tool **simply to test this hypothesis**, I suggest trying to **suppress** a `TransactionScope` (if there is one), which you can do via:

```
using (var tran = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        //... the rest of your code

        connection.Close();
    }                

    tran.Complete();
}
```

Note that the creation and `Open` of the `connection` must happen *inside* the suppressed region for it to count.

If this makes the issue go away, then: an ambient transaction was causing all the connections to become enlisted in a wider transaction - presumably a DTC transaction (since LTM transactions can re-use connections, IIRC).

So: *if* this fixes it, then frankly my advice would be to change the method to allow you to optionally pass the connection in as an input, allowing you to reuse a single connection for the 400 operations rather than leaning on the connection-pool.

---

Important: suppressing a transaction isn't usually a good idea; that transaction was there for a reason. The code here is **just** a diagnostic aid to investigate whether this is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. As it turns out, there was a (completely different method) which was `async`. I changed it to a `Task` (rather than `void`) and added an `await`. So @JeroenMostert was on the right track. I still don't get why the exception always occurred in a method which had nothing to do with the `async` part.

Comment: if you don't `await` something that is `async`, you can end up running concurrently - *very* concurrently if it is in a loop - so if that `async` code is what what called this method in a loop, then yes: that would very quickly eat the pool.